# How can I verify card PAN in text string?

Tags: java, luhn

I have string with any text. It can be like this - `"abcdef 123456789521 zxcvb"`, and - `"45651256"`, and - `"asdad 564654 sddsf 4"`. I want to search in text PAN number, that can be different length, and than verify it with `luhn` algorithm. I know, that I can to find it by regx, but it require expresion like this - `"Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}");`. But I don't know how many characters and digits and in what order my string will contains. May be anyone know how to do it? Any advice?

Comment: An advice: extract all the single words from the original string; for each word, check if it's a number; if so, consider that as the PAN.

Comment: @Andreaジーティーオー thanks, but I think, it can be difficult for server, which will do that. Because string can contains any numbers of characters and digits.

Comment: I see. But unfortunately, if you have a "random" text structure, a scanning of all the words is necessary (that is, the algorithm can only have a O(n) complexity).

Comment: @Andreaジーティーオー I agree with You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that by PAN you mean credit card number ([see PAN on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_card_number)).

According to that article, the numbers must be between 8 and 19 digits long. Thus, you search your text for numbers with a length in that interval, store them and check them with the [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm). Here's an implementation that finds numbers between 8-19 digits in length and performs the Luhn-check:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;    
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "helloWor4712389062l648977135536d 239012390oife234923 uiwed wq12893129038";

        ArrayList<String> result = getPossiblePANs(text);
        for(String pan : result) {
            System.out.print("Possible PAN: " + pan);
            if(luhnCheck(pan))
                System.out.println(" is valid!");
            else
                System.out.println(" is INVALID!");
        }
    }


    static ArrayList<String> getPossiblePANs(String text){  //Numbers w. 8-19 digits
        ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{8,19}+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        while(m.find())
            res.add(m.group());
        return res;
    }

    static boolean luhnCheck(String cardNumber){
        if(cardNumber.length() < 8 || cardNumber.length() > 19)
            return false;
        int sum = 0;
        int begin = cardNumber.length() - 2;
        for(int i = begin; i >= 0; i-=2){
            int number = Integer.parseInt(cardNumber.substring(i, i+1)) * 2;
            if(number > 9) sum += (number - 9);
            else sum += number;
        }
        return (sum % 10) == 0;
    }
}
```

---

```
Possible PAN: 4712389062 is INVALID!
Possible PAN: 648977135536 is INVALID!
Possible PAN: 239012390 is INVALID!
Possible PAN: 12893129038 is valid!
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(cardNumber.substring(i, i+1))` can be done much more efficiently with `cardNumber.charAt(i) - '0'`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I'm sure it can. I didn't write this with speed in mind, it is only a working implementation to get him started. Though I think `cardNumber.charAt(i) - '0'` is somewhat obscure. I know that you can do `char` arithmetic, but how does this really work?

Comment: @Tellus thanx! Great answer!

Comment: @VadimNovakovskiy No problem. Good luck coding!.

Comment: @VadimNovakovskiy I see that you no longer accept my answer. What's up? Is there anything else?